# No suitable driver for Oracle JDBC6 with maven standAlone java project

Tags: maven, driver, ojdbc

I have a Maven StandAlone java project, I added jdbc6.jar to my local maven repository and then write the dependecy in the pom file of the project, the jdbc6.jar is correctly added to /dependencies, but when I try to connect to my databaseI'm getting 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

It is in a NetBeans project, I probe the same code conection in Eclipse projet Without Maven and it works.

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant part of your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you refer below code for refer for Oracle JDBC6 connection.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
 Connection connection = null;
       try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
```

refer below link : http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-database-via-jdbc